# difference between AnypointPoint-mq subscriber and AnypointPoint mq consumer

Tags: mule, message-queue, mulesoft, cloudhub, mule4

anypoint mq subscriber and anypoint mq consumer.
what is the basic difference between anypoint mq subscriber and anypoint mq consumer.I know both can consume message but what are key difference?

***what is preftech  concept , please do not share mulesoft docs link , i am already aware about this , i am looking your practical knowledge based on your hand on.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Subscriber** is an Event source, which can be used to trigger a flow. It has inbuilt scheduler which you can configure for polling. (You are ready to consume message, but dont know when the message will come)

**Consumer** is an Event Processor, which cannot trigger a flow, therefore it can be used only after an event has generated. (You are sure a message is expected in the que)

**prefetch** is like assuming that the flow which the subscriber is triggering is capable of handling the messages. prefetch makes a copy in local buffer, which in turn signals that the message is already in use, so any other consumer or subscriber listening to the que will not get the message. The flow consumes the messages as per availability of threads.

Both works similarly but trade-offs can be only compared as per use case. So if you can give some perspective of your use case, we can compare. esp volume of messages, size of messages etc.

Comment: so in case i have set pre-fetch size 36 , so that means it will take 36 message at a time in local buffer and once these 36 message processed , it will take another 36 slot based on availability of messages, right?